# Is there benefit to tagging errors in Erlang?

Tags: error-handling, erlang

In Erlang there is a benefit to tagging successful return values (e.g. as shown in the [Erlang Programming Rules and Conventions](http://www.erlang.se/doc/programming_rules.shtml#REF32551)), but is there a benefit to tagging failure values? Specifically, is there benefit to the style of tagging used in the [file](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/file.html) package, where errors are tagged with the `error` atom? For instance, [`file:open`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/file.html#open-2) returns `{error, Reason}` when an error occurs, where `Reason` is a more descriptive atom, but is there a need for the `error` tag when you could just return the `Reason` atom directly? The only advantage I can currently see is that the tag documents the `Reason` atom as an error, but I feel the error atoms are self-descriptive and that this advantage is outweighed by having to "unbox" all future error values from this function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not just the `file` module that tags errors with an `error` atom; rather, this is a very common Erlang practice. The benefit is that any code wanting to check for an error without bothering with the reason can just match `{error, _Reason}` and take an appropriate action, whereas if it were to match `Reason` by itself — which, by the way, isn't always an atom — such matching would be quite varied depending on what's being called, and would also be harder to see in the code.

Comment: Yes, and you typically only tag return values, successful or error, when the function actually can return either. If the function crashes on error, a **very** common style (the Erlang "let it crash" philosophy), then there is no need to tag at all as you only see the successful return value anyway.